# use of extensions in visual force component

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom component and i want to use 2 controller classes for this but when i am using

```
extensions="RevController, myexten">
```

I am getting

> Error : Only StandardController and Apex Code controllers are
>   currently supported    please guide.

Comment: what is your standard controller?

Answer (score 1):

Custom components cannot utilize extensions. You can instantiate numerous objects, however, in a component controller's constructor. Ie:

```
public class customComponentCtrl {

    public customComponentCtrl(){
        //do stuff
        SomeOtherController soc = new SomeOtherController();
        //do other stuff with soc
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks Kevin......................................................